# Tricomi equation canonical form and solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Consider the Tricomi equation

$$u_{xx}+xu_{yy}=0$$

With the transformation $(r,q)=\left(-\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2},y\right)$, I found the canonical form but I could not solve it:

$$v_{qq}+v_{rr}+\dfrac1{3r}v_r=0.$$

Comment: This note from the arxiv will help you http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.3338v2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In the elliptic case $x>0$, the change of coordinates $(r,q) = \left(-x^{3/2},\frac{3}{2}y\right)$ in the Tricomi equation gives the [*Euler-Poisson-Darboux equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Poisson%E2%80%93Darboux_equation)
$$
u_{xx} + xu_{yy} = \tfrac{9}{4}x\left( u_{qq} + u_{rr} + \frac{1}{3r}u_r\right) = 0 .
$$
The functions $r,q$ satisfy the Beltrami differential equations
$$
r_x = -\sqrt{x}\, q_y,\qquad r_y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\, q_x .
$$
Particular solutions of the Tricomi equation can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Tricomi_equation).

---

Further reading: p. 162-163 of

R. Courant, D. Hilbert: *Methods of Mathematical Physics* vol. II: "Partial differential equations". Wiley-VCH, 1962. [doi:10.1002/9783527617234](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/9783527617234)